# Change Spring-boot static web resources location?

Tags: model-view-controller, thymeleaf, spring-boot

Base on this tutorial:

http://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

I can use the thymeleaf to serve the view in the location

```
/src/main/resources/templates/
```

However, I have to put the static web contents (css, js) in another location:

```
/src/main/webapp/resources
```

And linking the resources in the **hello.html** like that:

```
<link href="resources/hello.css" />
<script src="resources/hello.js"></script>
```

The directory structure is:

```
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── hello.java
        └──resources
            └──templates
               └──hello.html
        └──webapp
            └──resources
               └──hello.js
               └──hello.css
```

The problem is that the links of the static files are work when I run the web server. But if I open the **html** files in offline mode, the links are broken.

Could I move the static resource from

```
/src/main/webapp/resources
```

to:

```
/src/main/resources/templates/resources
```

The new directory structure would be like:

```
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── hello.java
        └──resources
            └──templates
               └──hello.html
               └──resources
                  └──hello.js
                  └──hello.css
```

I tried it but is doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `src/main/resources/static` (or `src/main/resources/public` or `src/main/resources/resources`). All those are registered by Spring Boot autoconfig.

Comment: thank you so much :) When trying to put the js and cs in the `src/main/resources/resources`, the link will be `http://localhost:8080/js`

Comment: The **html** files are in `src/main/resources/templates` but the static contents are in `src/main/resources/resources/js` and the links for static files when run web server are `http://localhost:8080/js/`. If the **html** link to `js/myfile.js` , it will be valid when running by web server. But it is broken in offline mode. How can I make the links be valid in both modes?

Comment: Maybe use `th:href="@{/js/foo.js}"` and `href="../resources/js/foo.js"`? Thymeleaf users must do this all the time, so I'm sure it's in the docs.

Comment: Mr Fly 911 , can you please post what th:href and href did you use in order to solve this problem?

Comment: @Tito <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{hello.css}" href="../resources/hello.css" />

Comment: I've tried all 3 and cannot get them to work. I have tried a series of combinations and moved stuff around but the css and js is being treated as if it was a template instead of static resource. I am running spring boot as a war if that makes a difference. I tried running it as a spring boot and also running it on top of tomcat8 but no luck. Please let me know if there is anythign you can recommend for me to try.

Answer (score 0):

Define the mapping in your context like following -

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/templates/**"
     location="classpath:/templates/" />
```

This will route everything that's hitting /template/ url to search for contents under your src/main/resources/templates/ folder.

In case you need tweaking in the url/prefix - adjust the mapping accordingly.

Comment: I don't think the OP was looking for an Xml solution, and this doesn't fix if anyway, BTW, because it's a static resource location and the question was about Thymeleaf templates.

Comment: I take that back (it's not about thymeleaf).

Comment: @Avnish Thanks you. But I use gradle, not maven.