# Web App (Spring, Angular, Grunt, Maven, Tomcat) running both grunt and tomcat servers

Tags: java, spring, angularjs, gruntjs, maven-tomcat-plugin

OK so I've been reading several of the other stack questions and trying to piece this together without much luck. Basically my approach is that I currently have one project with multiple sub-projects. I basically have the following:

```
root
|----backend
|----|----src
|----|----|----main
|----|----|----|----java (individual java files not shown)
|----|----|----|----resources
|----|----|----|----|----META-INF
|----|----|----|----|----|----applicationContext.xml
|----|----|----|----webapp
|----|----|----|----|----WEB-INF
|----|----|----|----|----|----web_servicesConfig.xml
|----|----|----|----|----|----web.xml
|----|----pom.xml
|----deploy
|----|----src
|----|----|----main
|----|----|----|----resources (properties files for tomcat)
|----|----pom.xml
|----frontend
|----|----app
|----|----|----angular files
|----|----bower_components
|----|----|----bower files
|----|----bower.json
|----|----Gruntfile.js
|----|----pom.xml
```

Ok hopefully that's clear enough on the file structure. I'm planning to use the maven-grunt-plugin so I can run my grunt commands on the frontend. The front end is basically the same setup as yo angular produces or that's at least the goal. Deploy simply sets up tomcat, and backend holds the Spring 4 restful services/api.

OK so this is were I'm confused and looking for help. I don't know how to get the frontend to work correctly with the backend. Basically I was wondering if there's a way to tell maven to start the Tomcat, and Grunt servers in dev mode so that I can use both of their features to quickly develop my project, and then pulling the min files into the war for the production build. I guess I can't figure out how to make everything play nicely together. I checked out this question which kind of talks about it but I'm still confused:

[How to deploy AngularJS app and Spring Restful API service on the same domain/server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920508/how-to-deploy-angularjs-app-and-spring-restful-api-service-on-the-same-domain-se)

I would love any links to tutorials that address how to use Maven with tomcat, spring, angularjs, and grunt...also bower so I can use it for my frontend package management. I've read several examples, and have seen many discussing on how to use spring with Java EE and jsp. Or using Gradle to do some things I want...but nothing exactly like I'm attempting.

Of course if this is a bad approach let me know. Basically I want to make my subproject as separated as possible while still allowing the developer to import/run from one pom file.

Answer (score 8):

from your question i digged up only two questions

1. How to do continuous development with grunt/bower  + tomcat
2. How to deploy for production

## 1 - Continuous development

The solution i have chosen for that  - since you already use `api` to communicate `client <-> server`- is to *separate* completely the two projects.

So what does it mean?
for me is to have two different repositories. One for client, One for Server
one this way you get few benefits:

- Split the work on the projects (front-end/server-side)
- Easier to maintain
- In case you want to support "API only" For an example, mobile application, and etc..

**But - How do they communicate while developing?**

This is a good question:
One solution is to run two server on localhost in parallel, i.e `mvn clean tomcat:run -P yourprofile; grunt server`

**But - I'll get cross domain if I try to access server-side from client-side from different port?**
You are right. And here you get the help of grunt and its plugin. grab a copy of [grunt-connect-proxy](https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy)

What is nice about this plugin that it acts as a middleware between grunt server and tomcat server so you ask grunt server for the API but actually grunt is asking tomcat server to answer on that (behind the scenes of course)

## 2 - Deploy for production

I guess this is a matter of personal preference question. I find the war file extremely big to do upload again and again (even if are able to share lib between all of your tomcat app). The solution I came up with is to do deploy over git.

**OK, but I have one big war file. How can I do that?**

For me I use a deploy script I wrote in bash. This is what it does:

1. Tag the current source
2. Run mvn clean package war:exploded -P your-prod-profile (this will run test and integration test as well)
3. With the above command you get all your complied project's file in one place, instead of one big war file.
4. Copy all those files (and inner paths) into outside folder (I use another repository for maintenance deployment over git. So basically I have 3 repositories. One for server source, one for client source, and one for server binaries.)
5. Before doing 4 make sure to delete all files and folders (besides .git stuff) from it
6. After 4 do "git add -A"
7. "git commit -a -m 'new production version X"
8. You can mark some tags before and after for allowing easy way of recovering the last code if there was a big bug in the new production
9. Run remote command on server to a.) stop server, b.) pull the last changes from the binary repository, c.) run server again.
10. For me what I did is a symbolic link between tomcat app to an outside folder (the binary repository) so

Hope this will give you some directions,

Bests,
Oak

Comment: Thanks, for the response, I like your answers. I'm still new so I can't click it as useful as I don't have enough reputation yet. :-(

Comment: Awesome awesome, thanks a bunch! Exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

OK so i wanted to post a solution that works well for my local development, and has allowed me to use the desired approach...is to do as Oak stated (sorry I'm not sure how to link his username) and have two separate builds/projects. However, my front-end project uses grunt to serve up my code on a specific port, with some middleware that directs requests on the port to either the front-end code, or to the server running spring-boot. This allows me to act as if the code is really running on the same project and avoid any CORS and other issues from running them on different domains/servers. here's the section of code in my grunt build that allows me to do that:

```
livereload: {
    options: {
      debug: true,
      middleware: function (connect, options) {
        var middlewares = [];

        middlewares.push(rewriteModule.getMiddleware([
          //Load App under context-root of 'myappcontext/secured'
          {from: '^/napiweb/(.*)$', to: '/$1'},

          //Redirect slash to myappcontext/secured as convenience
          {from: '^/$', to: '/napiweb', redirect: 'permanent'}

          //Send a 404 for anything else
          //{from: '^/.+$', to: '/404'}
        ]));

        if (!Array.isArray(options.base)) {
          options.base = [options.base];
        }

        options.base.forEach(function () {
          // Serve static files.
          middlewares.push(connect.static('.tmp'),
            connect().use(
              '/bower_components',
              connect.static('./bower_components')
            ),
            connect.static(appConfig.app));
        });

        // Make directory browse-able.
        //middlewares.push(connect.directory(directory));

        return middlewares;
      }
    }
  },
```

Then I configured my spring-boot to have a proxy for local development that forwards specific requests to the front-end. It is set up as follows: in my config.xml file

```
<config proxy-port="{{http-port}}" console-port="1776">
  <console-recording sso="true" rest="true" max-entries="100" enable-debug- logging='true'/>
  <sso-cookie name="wamulator" domain=".somedomain.com" session-timeout-seconds="1800"/>
  <port-access local-traffic-only="false"/>
  <sso-traffic strip-empty-headers="true">
     <by-site host="localhost.somedomain.com" port="{{http-port}}">

       <cctx-mapping thost="127.0.0.1" tport="8081">
         <policy-source>xml={{policy-src-xml}}</policy-source>
       </cctx-mapping>
       <cctx-mapping thost="127.0.0.1" tport="9000">
         <policy-source>xml={{static-src-xml}}</policy-source>
       </cctx-mapping>
       <cctx-mapping thost="127.0.0.1" tport="8180">
         <policy-source>xml={{napi-src-xml}}</policy-source>
       </cctx-mapping>
     </by-site>
  </sso-traffic>

 <user-source type='xml'>xml={{usr-src-xml}}</user-source>
 <proxy-timeout inboundMillis="0" outboundMillis="0" />
</config>
```

As you can see the cctx mapping will direct some request to the front end being served up on port 9000 and some to the backend serving up the APIs.This is based off the policy-config.xml and static-config.xml files. They are almost exactly the same, and the only difference is in the authHost and cctx setting here's one for an example:

```
<deployment at='2013-01-31_16:25:12.205-0700'>
   <environment id='dev' host='dev.somedomain.com (exposee)'/>
   <application id='napi-rest' authHost='localhost.somedomain.com/napiweb/api' cctx='/napiweb/api'>
   <authentication scheme='anonymous' name='Anonymous Authentication'> </authentication>
   <authorization failure-redirect-url='/denied.html'>
   <default format='exposee' value='Allow Authenticated Users'>
     <headers>
       <success>
         ...profile-att specific for my organization
       </success>
       <failure>
         <redirect value='/denied.html'/>
       </failure>
     </headers>
  </default>
  <rule name='Allow Authenticated Users' enabled='true' allow-takes-precedence='false'>
    <allow>
      <condition type='role' value='Anyone'/>
    </allow>
  </rule>
</authorization>
```

The only other difference is the other file has `authHost='localhost.somedomain.com/napiweb/' cctx='/napiweb/'` This causes the APIs to be called and the front-end to be called as if they are served up from the same project. Then when we push the projects up to our repositories, we have two build cycles. One takes the front end and creates static assets using `grunt build` and then copies those files over to the rest server so it can serve them up. This allows us to have separate projects for development but a single server serving up our site. Not ideal...as ultimately I think we should have separate servers/instances for the front and back, but since we weren't allowed to do so, this allowed us to act as if we did during development. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I only provided this as I notice this post was getting a lot of views and maybe someone wanted some code to help them get started.