# How to use jsp and grunt server at the same time

Tags: jsp, gruntjs

Here's my current dev setting for my web app.

The entry page is a static html file, say index.html.  I don't really want to care about the server end services, so what I'm doing now is to start a local grunt http server to load all my local javascript files and other resources, and use grunt proxy to redirect all client REST requests to a real server to get data.  This makes it very easy because I don't really need to setup the server environment and I can actually use any existing server as long as it provides those REST apis that the client needs.

However, one day, I figured I need server to tell me some information at the first response.  So, what I can think of is changing the index.html to index.jsp.  I really don't want to do another request to server after the index.html and its javascript files are downloaded because of performance concern.  So, how can I still use grunt server as I used to do?

Comment: Not really, at least, not easily. The server you run with Grunt is in Node.js (JavaScript) and has no idea what a jsp is or how to execute it. It would be possible to invoke a Java program using simple CLI execution within the Grunt server code, but even then, rendering a JSP would be really difficult if even possible.

Comment: Thanks!  Have to use it another way then.

Comment: closest I came across to this is mentioned here [http://stackoverflow.com/a/25279454/234110]