# Serve AngularJS application with Spring Web MVC

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Tomcat server running Spring 4.1.6.

Spring exposes a REST API which is consumed by an AngularJS frontend.

Now I tried serving the frontend (.html, .js, .css, .jpg) with Spring Web MVC. Apparently this is pretty easy in Spring boot by placing the content in dedicated directories ([How to deploy AngularJS app and Spring Restful API service on the same domain/server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920508/how-to-deploy-angularjs-app-and-spring-restful-api-service-on-the-same-domain-se)).

But how do I do the same on Spring Web MVC? I've tried different things but so far only received a lot of 404s when I tried to access the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to configure your application context with

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

and then put the files in WEB-INF/resources/ folder