# Setup AngularJS and Jersey webservice

Tags: java, angularjs, web-services, maven

I developed an app with `angularJS`, but I'm a newbie to `Maven` and I don't know how to setup my project so both can communicate.

`AngularJS` project is on an Apache server on port 80.
`Jersey Webservice` is on a Grizzly servlet container on port 8080.

Problem is I want both on the same server/port.

Can I run the webservice in Apache?
**NO, it needs to run on a servlet container (Tomcat, Grizzly)**

Can I run the AngularJS project in grizzly/Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a war with maven. But wamp server is made for PHP/MySql. you need something else like grizzly or Tomcat. Also,you do not need the applications running in the same port, the gracefulness of webservices is that you can connect to another server

Comment: AngularJS and REST API needs to be on the same server. Please check updated question.

Comment: take a look at this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920508/how-to-deploy-angularjs-app-and-spring-restful-api-service-on-the-same-domain-se)