# why does tomcat redirect away from angularjs petclinic?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am decomposing [the angularjs branch of the spring petclinic](https://github.com/singularity-sg/spring-petclinic) to figure out how it works.  When I run it in eclipse on my local devbox, it works perfectly at the url `localhost : 8080 / petclinic`, serving up the following main page:

[image]

But when I bundle it into a war and deploy it at a remote tomcat web server as the root war for somedomain.com, requests for somedomain.com result in the following generic login page:

[image]

To determine whether or not it was  due to the JavaScript code in the petclinic angularJS app, I deleted all contents of [src/main/webapp](https://github.com/singularity-sg/spring-petclinic) and replaced them with a minimal Hello World AngularJS app within the rest of the petclinic sample app, but the same problem also results when I redeploy the minimal "Hello World" version of the war to the `somedomain.com` server.

I also looked for `SecurityConfig.java`, but there is no such file in the download.  And I read all of [the spring config files](https://github.com/singularity-sg/spring-petclinic), but could not identify any security parameters.

You can recreate this problem yourself in a few minutes by taking the following simple steps:

1.) Navigate to /home/username/git

2.) git clone https://github.com/singularity-sg/spring-petclinic.git

3.) Eclipse -> File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven project

4.) Eclipse -> Project Explorer -> Rt-Click-Project -> Maven -> Download Sources

5.) Eclipse -> Project Explorer -> Rt-Click-Project -> Maven -> Update Project

6.) Eclipse -> Project Explorer -> Rt-Click-Project -> Run As..Maven Build...war:war

7.) Deploy the war to a remote tomcat server in the directory for somedomain.com and rename it ROOT.war

8.) Type somedomain.com in your web browser.

This question is about the AngularJS branch of the Spring Petclinic.  But for comparison, I also repeated the above steps with [this other AngularJS Spring MVC sample app](https://github.com/xvitcoder/spring-mvc-angularjs), which also works fine in eclipse, and which ALSO SERVES THE SAME GENERIC LOGIN PAGE when hosted at somedomain.com.

**So why doesn't tomcat serve up the petclinic app when it is packaged as `ROOT.war` and served up in response to requests for `somedomain.com`?**

Comment: Are you sure you are deploying it?  I don't see the word `Login` in either git repo you link to. If the code for the file you are showing isn't in their repo, it seems like you must be serving something else.

Comment: @pherris Thank you. I'm sure the war is in the folder that serves the war file. A login page like that is generated automatically by spring security. I have manually removed the old ROOT directory and war before deploying each new test war. Content in this OP results from opening port 8080 and accessing tomcat directly from somedomain.com:8080. Separately, the app is also behind a reverse proxy that is accessed by somedomain.com, which is the subject of another OP. Tomcat server.xml is same for both: http://serverfault.com/questions/733447/why-does-apache-tomcat-reverse-proxy-give-502-errors